# Does stand alone spring boot application run on embedded Tomcat all the time?

Tags: spring-boot

I just got into spring boot application tutorial (for release 1.5.8). I created a simple hello world stand alone application that enables log (log4j2). When I executed the application, I got an error port 8080 is already in use. I was a bit confused I thought this app is stand alone program which would not require web container or application server. You could deploy it though based on reading I think.

To avoid the exception I made it work by providing parameter `--server.port=8181` after reading upon some articles about it.

I read that spring boot has embedded Tomcat web container. My question is, "Does stand alone spring boot application would be running within the embedded Tomcat unless I configure it otherwise?"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on the starters you include in your dependencies. Including spring-boot-starter-web will lead to the default behavior you are seeing.

You can choose to exclude this starter if you do not need it anyway.

Another way is to mark your application not to be a web application. The easiest way to do so is setting is directly before starting your application:

```
SpringApplication.setWebEnvironment(false)
```

Comment: Your explanation surely expands my bare minimum understanding on spring boot. Yes, I include spring-boot-starter-web as dependency. Bear with me one more question. If I want it to be running this app as a rest web service, running it on embedded Tomcat would be one way to do it, right?

Comment: Of course. It starts up a full featured tomcat, which is meant to be used :). You can configure a lot of things with properties. Take a look at https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/common-application-properties.html and search for tomcat.

Comment: That last suggestion should be to call `SpringApplication.setWebEnvironment(WebApplicationType.NONE);`

Comment: It's also not clear where in the startup process I could even call the `setWebEnvironment()` method.